# Neural network and machine learning?

Tags: python, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ROS node/facility to implement machine learning via Artificial Neural Network (ANN) ? I know, I can write my own C++ and Python codes. However since topics as navigation, SLAM and face recognition has some inbuilt resources at ROS, so I was hoping that ANN may also have such a node/package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29523/neural-network-and-machine-learning-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-03-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/) to create a reinforcement learning application that was using gazebo simulator with pr2, and had rewards based on the topics published by the simulator and the robot nodes.

I believe that the ANN doesn't need to be part of ROS, you just need to implement your publishers subscribers.

By the way, pybrain is pretty powerful, and the ANN has an ok documentation, but the reinforcement learning classes are awfully documented.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) with karma: 651 on 2012-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-12**:
@Victor Are your codes/ideas on the public domain ?

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2012-03-12**:
No, as it was just an experiment for a course at my AI master, but I'll gladly send it to you by email if you are interested.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-12**:
@Victor Thank you, please send it to my email arkapravobhaumik at gmail dot com. In case I make any fruitful use of your work, I will cite you/your lab etc.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-03-12**:
@Arkapravo OpenCV also includes a fairly extensive collection of machine learning routines including neural networks.  See http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/ml/doc/ml.html.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-12**:
@Pi Robot Thank you - will check it out !

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-08-04**:
@Victor can I have also copy of your codes/ideas?

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2013-08-06**:
Sure just let me know your email address.
Recently I've been experimenting with what Arkapravo suggests, and I find opencv Machine Learning library much more powerful than pybrain and better documented. I would go with that one

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-08-06**:
Ok, thanks. My email adress is bojan_andonovski@yahoo.de

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-08-07**:
Hi Victor.. Did you already send it?? Sorry to disturb but I did not get it...

**Comment by [aabi_zharf](https://answers.ros.org/users/7601/aabi_zharf/) on 2013-10-16**:
@Victor I hope this is not starting to be a hassle for you. Could I have a copy of your code as well? My email address is aabi_zharf@yahoo.com. I am familiar with PyBrain and I'm trying to setup a training experiment where the robot's joints are controlled by an ANN, not using RL though.  Thanks!

**Comment by [Emad_Mohammed](https://answers.ros.org/users/35500/emad_mohammed/) on 2018-05-26**:
@victor could you send me the same files if you do not mind?
emadmahrousawwad at gmail dot com

**Comment by [grzegorz.jamrowski@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/38538/grzegorz.jamrowski@gmail.com/) on 2018-11-14**:
@Victor I am facing similar problem as like as friends above. Could you send me the same files if you dont mind? grzegorz.jamrowski at gmail dot com - Im not quite good at Phyton or C++ but I know how to use ROS ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used [libSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/) and [shogun](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/) wrapped around with a ros node that subscribes/publishes learning-specific data. But I guess you would need something else if you are to use ANN.

An up-to-date list that shows what most popular ML tools support can be seen [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aunb9cCVAP6NdDVBMzY1TjdPcmx4ei1EeUZNNGtKUHc&hl=en#gid=0).

---

Originally posted by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) with karma: 288 on 2012-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd recommend this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

- Python
- open source
- good tutorials
- widely used
- effective where needed, for example: using LibSVM under the SVM classes

---

Originally posted by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) with karma: 358 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emad_Mohammed](https://answers.ros.org/users/35500/emad_mohammed/) on 2018-05-26**:
@victor could you send me the same files if you do not mind?
emadmahrousawwad at gmail dot com